# HMSMap Not Displaying on Device

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-map-kit

I'm working on a React Native project and recently updated HMSMap to its latest version. After the update, the map is not displaying on the device; it just shows a blank screen. I'm using HMSMap version 6.11.2-301.

Downgrading HMSMap: Initially, I was using version [6.11.2-301], and I downgraded to [6.11.0-300] to see if that would resolve the issue.

Following Documentation: I meticulously followed all the configuration steps provided in the HMSMap documentation for the downgraded version.

Downgrading Gradle: Additionally, I attempted to downgrade Gradle in my project, thinking it might be a compatibility issue.